# Execute AWS CDK in Lambda environment

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I need to dynamically create git branch testing resources on AWS. So, I need to 
webhook -> api gateway -> lambda -> provision resources.

I wrote an example to let AWS CDK can be executed in AWS Lambda environment.

https://github.com/imyoungyang/cdk-in-lambda

Comment: what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that you need to create aws credential and config file in the /tmp path because the default path is at `Lambda default HOME is /home/usrXXX.`

You can see the lambda index.js to get more detail information:

https://github.com/imyoungyang/cdk-in-lambda/blob/master/cdkInit/index.js#L42

Comment: you talking to yourself?